# Why is firebase undefined when used with electron?

Tags: firebase, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I have the following:

- Fresh install of electron-react-boilerplate
- firebase ^9.8.4 in package.json

In renderer I have the following code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const config = {
  /* ACTUAL CONFIG FROM FIREBASE CONSOLE */
  /* snip */
};

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config, 'default');
```

When I `npm start` I get the following error in the renderer window:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initializeApp')

It appears firebase is undefined.  All other packages I've added worked fine.  What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Google changed the syntax required between version 8 and version 9.  While many examples abound on how to use firebase, many are based on version 8 which allows the above syntax.  When using version 9, the following syntax is used:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const config = {
  /* ACTUAL CONFIG FROM FIREBASE CONSOLE */
  /* snip */
};

const fire = initializeApp(config, 'default');
```